# I was expecting 0 and 1 as an answer of a predict function in r

Tags: r, generalized-linear-model, prediction, caret

I'm doing a binomial family with method="glm" in train function (caret package) and as result I'm getting predicted numbers like "0.62325028 0.51807017 0.67119878 ..." and I was expecting vector containing something like "0 1 1 0 ..."

Here is my code that reproduces vector with those values:

```
   library(ElemStatLearn)
        library(caret)

        data(SAheart)

        set.seed(7799)

        train = createDataPartition(SAheart$chd, p=.75, list=FALSE)
        trainSA = SAheart[train,]
        testSA = SAheart[-train,]

        set.seed(3567)


        glmFM.01 = train(chd ~ age + alcohol,
                         data=trainSA,
                         method="glm",
                         family="binomial"
        )

        predVec = predict(glmFM.01, newdata=testSA)
```

Variable "chd" consists of only two values: 0 and 1. Why am I not getting predicted values 0 and 1?

Comment: After you got  (seemingly) strange results from the `predict.glm` function, did you take a moment to read the documentation at `?predict.glm`? Because the answer to your question is there.

Comment: Because that's not how logistic regression (glm+binomial) works. I suggest you consult a statistician rather than a programmer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is related to how the data are encoded:

```
> str(SAheart$chd)
 int [1:462] 1 1 0 1 1 0 0 1 0 1 ...
```

Most functions in R that do classification expect a factor vector. Since the output is a number, `train` thinks that you are doing regression (despite you passing `family` in).

Convert it to a factor (and don't use "0" and "1" as levels) and you'll get the appropriate result (a factor output).

Max

Comment: The OP is about the value of `predVec` not `SAheart$chd`